# writing a linq query like statement in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, linq, knockout.js

In my javascript file i would like to display my results using linq query like statement. 
Below is my view model and information regarding how i'm getting the info.

```
var viewModel = {
    RosterRoleTypes: ko.observableArray([])
};

// the ViewModel for the array of RoleTypes
var roleTypesViewModel = function (data) {
    roleTypesViewModel.AddRoles(data);
}

// Adds multiple roles to the array of RoleTypes
roleTypesViewModel.AddRoles = function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        roleTypesViewModel.PushRole(value);
    });
};

//Add a single role to the array of Roles
roleTypesViewModel.PushRole = function (role) {
    viewModel.RosterRoleTypes.push(new roleViewModel(role));
}

// the ViewModel for a single Role
var roleViewModel = function (data) {
    var _self = this;
    _self.ContentRole = ko.observable(data.ContentRole);
    _self.RoleName = ko.observable(data.RoleName);
    _self.RoleRank = ko.observable(data.RoleRank);
    _self.UserCount = ko.observable(data.UserCount);
};
```

In my `OnSuccess` in the get method i would like to do something like the following:

```
var results = Enumerable.From(viewModel)
    .ForEach(RoleTypes){ show RoleName and UserCount}
```

How can i properly write that statement using Enumerable.From...

Comment: I have heard of chaining in javascript but I am not familiar with it. My impression is that you can chain commands together and the next command will take the output from the first command. Maybe google underscore js chaining example or something

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried LINQ.js it sounds like exactly what you are looking for. You can find it here: http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Here are some examples right from their site:

```
// C# LINQ (delegate)
Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Where(delegate(int i) { return i % 3 == 0; })
    .Select(delegate(int i) { return i * 10; });
// linq.js - anonymous function
Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Where(function(i) { return i % 3 == 0; })
    .Select(function(i) { return i * 10; });
// C# LINQ (lambda)
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Where(i => i % 3 == 0).Select(i => i * 10);
// linq.js - lambda expression
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Where("i => i % 3 == 0").Select("i => i * 10");
// $ is default iterator variable like Scala's "_" or Groovy's "it"
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Where("$ % 3 == 0").Select("$ * 10");
 // "" is shorthand of "x => x" (identity function)
Enumerable.Range(4, 7).Join(Enumerable.Range(8, 5), "", "", "outer,inner=>outer*inner");

// Enumerable.From is wrap from primitive array, string(to charArray), object(to KeyValuePair[]) etc..
var array = [100, 200, 30, 40, 500, 40, 200];
var ex1 = Enumerable.From(array).Distinct().ToArray(); // [100, 200, 30, 40, 500]
var ex2 = Enumerable.From("foobar").ToArray(); // ["f", "o", "o", "b", "a", "r"];
var ex3 = Enumerable.From({foo:10, bar:20}).ToArray(); // [{Key:"foo",Value:10}, {Key:"bar",Value:20}]

// C# - AnonymousType
array.Select((val, i) => new { Value = val, Index = i });
// linq.js - object literal
Enumerable.From(array).Select("val,i=>{Value:val, Index:i}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Although it is not clear from start, you can chain function calls.

Also there is [JSLINQ](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/) which follows naming more like LINQ.

This is what I would write with underscore:

```
_.(viewModel.RosterRoleTypes()).each(function(item){
 console.log(item.RoleName());
 console.log(item.UserCount());
});
```

But if you only want to iterate the items you could even use Jquery $.each